# check the user type mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to use different user types on the login page. In my mysqli database i have users with functions. Function = 1, function = 2. On the dashboard page I want to show different data on the user types. This is my code to show different data with the types:

```
 <?php
   $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT functie FROM users");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
      if($row['functie']=='1')
        { ?>
          <p>12:00 - 14:00: Receptie Kerk</p>
          <span>Adres</span>
          <hr>
          <p>15:00 - 16:00: Restaurant</p>
          <span>Adres</span>
          <hr>
          <p>18:00 - 20:00: Restaurant</p>
          <span>Adres</span>
          <hr>
          <?php }
            if($row['functie']=='2')
             {
             ?>
               <p>18:00 - 20:00: Restaurant</p>
               <span>Adres</span>
               <hr>
               <?php } ?>
```

Now it shows all the data on both users, but that's not allowed. How can I this get worked?

Comment: you need a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: And what must be in the WHERE clause?

Comment: someone gave you an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

in checklogin file :

```
<?php
// do SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=$user and pass=$pass
//after checking the inputs posted 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
session_start();
$_SESSION['fonctie'] = $data['fonctie'];
?>
```

in the dashbord file

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION['fonctie']))
        die('No Permission!');


         if($_SESSION['fonctie']==1)
          { 
               echo ' <p>12:00 - 14:00: Receptie Kerk</p>
                      <span>Adres</span>
                      <hr>
                      <p>15:00 - 16:00: Restaurant</p>
                     <span>Adres</span>
                     <hr>
                     <p>18:00 - 20:00: Restaurant</p>
                     <span>Adres</span>
                     <hr>';
               }else
                   {

                   echo  '<p>18:00 - 20:00: Restaurant</p>
                         <span>Adres</span>
                         <hr>';
                    } ?>
```

- the checking should have the same type (Integer == Integer) if Varchar use `"1"` instead of `'1'`
- do not forget the `WHERE` in your query to get a single row in result

Comment: *"do not forget the WHERE in your query to get a single row in result"* - They'll be asking  you how to do that; they asked me. It isn't up to me to tell them that, it's up to you, and in your answer.

Comment: @DzNiT0 And what must be in the WHERE clause? Something like: WHERE functie = 1?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thnk u

Comment: @DzNiT0 this for my dashboard page. The username and password input happens through the checklogin.php. That is an other page.

Comment: @JulianRouw so the user is already logged ? so you want to give each a special permission !

Comment: @JulianRouw i have updated my answer i hope that will help you

Comment: @DzNiT0 i get the message "No Permission". I dont know whats gone wrong

Comment: in you checklog file you should start a session and set your global session variable as i explained

Comment: @DzNiT0 This is my checklogin file: $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";
    //voer de query uit
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    //controleer of de login correct was

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)

        //start de sessie
    {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['fonctie'] = $data['fonctie']; but i get also the message "No Permission".

Comment: try echo $_SESSION_['fonctie'] and see what gives you

Comment: @DzNiT0 It works! An little typing error. Thanks for the help!